# Traverse HTML in depth with jsoup

Tags: java, css-selectors, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to scrape some data from a page, but I am a beginner to jsoup - and not that experienced a java developer :)

The html example is:

```
<tr class="divider">
    <td class="betona text">hello1</td>
    <td>1 712 000</td>
    <td>3 661 000</td>
    <td>1 727 000</td>
    <td>1 011 000</td>
    <td>14 813 000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="text">hello2</td>
    <td>1,84</td>
    <td>4,85</td>
    <td>2,29</td>
    <td>1,34</td>
    <td>19,61</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="text">hello3</td>
    <td>931 739 034</td>
    <td>755 407 422</td>
    <td>755 407 422</td>
    <td>755 407 422</td>
    <td>755 407 422</td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th class="text">hello4</th>
    <th>2011</th>
    <th>2010</th>
    <th>2009</th>
    <th>2008</th>
    <th>2007</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="text">hello5</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>8 800 000</td>
    <td>9 302 000</td>
    <td>9 312 000</td>
</tr>
```

I can get a list displaying `hello1 hello2...` etc with the following code - but how can I get these data below `hello4` if that's the only thing I need?

```
931 739 034

755 407 422

755 407 422

755 407 422

755 407 422
```

The java I am using currently is this:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

Elements data = document.select("td[class=text]");
System.out.println("datatest1: " + data.first() + "\n");
for (Element dat : data) {
    System.out.println("datatest2: " + dat.text()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the HTML code given so far, it are exclusively `<th>` elements without `class="text"`.

So, this should do:

```
Elements data = document.select("th:not(.text)");
```

#### See also:

- [Jsoup selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)
- [Jsoup `Selector` API](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)